# Youtube thumbnail does not appear always

Tags: html, video, youtube, video-thumbnails

I am showing a list of youtube videos on my client's site. All videos have thumbnail. I have used the following code:

```
<object style="display: block;" width="300" height="250" data="https://www.youtube.com/v/wK_JI0UxY3g?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/wK_JI0UxY3g?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" />
<param name="src" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/wK_JI0UxY3g?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" />
</object>
```

I am displaying 5 videos on the page. Strangely, thumbnail appears on some videos (randomly).

Is there any attribute to specify that "thumbnail should appear compulsorily"? I've tried `showlist=1` which does not solve the issue.

Comment: Is that the embed code from youtube?

Comment: No, I have used simple old object tag and replaced the ID of the URL

Comment: Maybe this is your answer.. Maybe the don't support this code anymore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to youtube's docs, this embed code is deprecation.

> Deprecation Notice
>   YouTube  embeds were deprecated on January 27, 2015. Please migrate your applications to use  embeds, which can intelligently use whichever embedded player – HTML (`<video>`) or Flash (`<object>`) – the client supports.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. The section which says "embed a player using an <iframe> tag" is what I needed to know :)
It worked using iframe